# Actual Velocity and Average Velocity

Tags: calculus

I was given a table with time $x$ and Speed $f(x)$. The inputs and outputs are $f(3:00)=7.2$, $f(3:10)=7.9$, $f(3:20)=8.2$, $f(3:30)=7.6$, $f(3:40)=7.8.$ The function is assumed to be continuous in the problem.

I have found the average speed using trapezoid rule (which was part (a) of a $4$ part problem): $$\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{2n} = \frac{3 \cdot 67 - 3}{2(4)} = \frac{.67}{8} = .08\overline{33}.$$

$$\text{distance} =.08 \overline{33}(7.2+2(7.9)+2(8.2)+2(7.6.)+7.8) = 5.2 \text{ km}.$$

$$\frac{1}{b-a}(5.2)= \text{average speed} = \frac{1}{.67}(5.2) = 7.8 \text{km/h}.$$

The next part asks what time(s) during the given interval would the river's actual velocity match the estimated average velocity. I know that at $3:40$ the velocity matches the average velocity, but I also know that between $3:00$ and $3:10$ along with in between $3:20$ and $3:30$ there will be a time when the velocity is $7.8$ (IVT).

I am not sure how to find these values.

Comment: use the interpolation to find the function of velocity with time then you can find any required value or you can graph the data

Comment: what is the interpolation?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: can you help me find the function?

Comment: post what you tried to help you

Comment: Without knowing more about $f$, there’s no way to answer this. Even invoking the IVT to say that the time has to be between 3:00 and 3:10 assumes that $f$ is continuous in that interval. What other information about $f$ were you given or have deduced in the preceding parts of the problem?

Comment: I was not given anything else...

Comment: There must at least be some context for this exercise. What topics did the text cover in the material leading up to it?

Comment: It covered position, velocity, and acceleration functions as antiderivatives

Answer (score 0):

the graph of data is 
[image]

now think to know what you need

Comment: Well, only the red dots are the graph of the data. The specific blue curve you’ve drawn isn’t really justified by anything in the question.

Comment: @amd the best way is firstly finding the function of data by interpolation and then plot it to get the above curve

Comment: There is no information in the question that justifies using Lagrange interpolation, or any other method, for that matter. One could just as well join the data points with straight lines.

Comment: @amd anyhow, I gave him the main idea to solve it